# Python tarfile: how to use tar+gzip compression with follow symbolic link?

Tags: python, gzip, tar, dereference, tarfile

How could I use tar+gzip compression with "follow symbolic link" feature in Python 3.4? The problem is:

- tarfile.open() supports "w:gz" mode but does not support "dereference" option
- tarfile.tarfile() supports "dereference" but does not support "w:gz" mode

Code:

```
...
mode = ""
if bckentry['method'] == "tar":
    mode = "w"
elif bckentry['method'] == "targz":
    mode = "w:gz"

archive = tarfile.TarFile(name=filepath, mode=mode)
archive.dereference = True if bckentry['followsym'] == "yes" else False
# archive = tarfile.open(filepath, mode=mode)

if bckentry['withpath'] == 'yes':
    for entry in bckentry['include_dirs']:
        archive.add(entry, filter=self.filter_tar)
elif bckentry['withpath'] == 'no':
    for entry in bckentry['include_dirs']:
        archive.add(entry, arcname=os.path.basename(entry), filter=self.filter_tar)
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) is a shortcut for the [`TarFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.open) classmethod, that in turn calls the [`TarFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile-objects) constructor. The documentation is a bit vague, but from the code it is apparent that the first two will pass the `dereference` keyword argument and all other unconsumed kwargs to the `TarFile` constructor.

Thus you can use `dereference` with any of them, if you just pass it as a keyword argument:

```
archive = tarfile.open(name='foo.tar.gz', mode='w:gz', dereference=True)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks man, I read the documentation and just didn't try this obvious method.